# SQL return both table rows separately

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables and want to return both table's rows. Both tables do not have any relation.

`Table 1` has columns `userid, name`, and other columns... and `Table 2` has only two columns `id, name`.

I want both table results in one query result set.

Table results:

```
userid name and other columns from Table 1.
id     name and NULL, NULL should show as Table 2 do not have extra columns.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `union`

```
select userid, name, col1, col2, col3 from table1
union all
select id, name, null, null, null from table2
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with union but there are lots of column in table1 and I have to add lots of null for it.

Comment: +1 @Keyur - You should alter you question and let people know what your *real* problem is. From your comments, your real problem is that you don't wish to add all the null columns. fwiw - I doubt you will have any other choice.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I have to add null multiple times .. my question is fairly related with union. Because I want only 2 columns from second table and 50+ columns from first table. Thats it..

Comment: @Keyur: if you want to use `UNION`, your data sets have to have the identical number of columns (and identical datatypes, too). You cannot do it any other way.

Comment: @Keyur Is there a reason you want these two disparate resultsets in a single result set?

Comment: @Keyur, syntax of UNION enforce to specify the columns explicitly. The purpose of union is to merge different resultsets as one single output. So you have to tell SQLSERVER what columns needs to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

```
select userid, name, col1, col2, col3 from table1
union all
select id, name, null, null, null from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
(SELECT userid, name, column3, column4, column5 FROM table1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, name, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM table2)
```